# PHP write file to csv

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that include URLs. I use the following PHP code to read from the csv file(text.csv) and search and get the file content with "file_get_contents" for the relevant URL. I need to write this data into another csv file(file.csv). That is where I got stuck. Any help with a better code is appreciated.

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
if (($handle = fopen("text.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 500, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $homepage = file_get_contents($data[$c]);
            echo $homepage . "</br>";
        }
    }
   fclose($handle);
}
```

UPDATE

I figured out most of the things. Thank you FirstOne. Now the only problem is In the "file.csv" file all the records are inserted in the first row. So only the final file_put_content value is in the csv file.

New Code

```
if (($handle = fopen("text.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 500, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $file = 'file.csv';
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $str = file_get_contents($data[$c]) . "\n";
            $json = json_decode($str, true);
            $status = $json['status'].PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents($file, $status);
        }
    }
   fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What part are you having difficulties with? Have you tried using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)?

Comment: I added the new code. Can you give me the solution

Comment: By the update, you're replacing the content of the file each time. If you want different files, you need to change the file name in the loop (`$file = something_probably_a_counter`). If you want to append the value, you have to pass a flag to the function, as mentioned in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: Something is wrong with the PHP_EOL global var.  Try just using "\n"

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I solved it. the problem is that I have not append it. Now only I understood it